# How to Connect Synergy over WPA2 Enterprise networks?

Tags: synergy, wpa

Situation: Using Synergy to control two computers.

Problem: School network is a WPA2 Enterprise network, not able to connect both Synergy-s to one another.

Question: Is this a Synergy problem (i.e. It cannot connect over WPA2 Enterprise networks) or is it my School's network problem (i.e. Firewalls, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synergy doesn't know that the underlying network is WPA-Enterprise, nor does it care – as long as it can send IP packets.

Whether computer 1 can reach computer 2 depends entirely on the specific network configuration. For example, the school might have enabled "client isolation" in all APs (to prevent malware from spreading). See if you can at least ping the other host.

Comment: I can actually ping each other, but another issue is that the pings are inconsistent, which is maybe why Synergy cannot connect (expecting a reply). But thank you so much for the information!